# R - How to split a data frame into a list of data frames with specific header combinations

Tags: r

I'm extremely new to R and could use some help.

I'm trying to split a data frame into a list of data frames that consists of every possible pair of column 1 with each subsequent column.

For example, given the following data:

```
df <- data.frame ("Time" = c("Mon","TUE", "WED"), VarA = c(2,5,6), VarB = c(24,46,14))
```

I'd like to end up with two data frames contained within a list. The first would be columns "Time" and "VarA", and the second would be columns "Time" and "VarB".

Ideally the function that creates this list would be scalable for hundreds of time-variable pairs. The end goal is to have a list of data frames so that I can use `lapply` to run various calculations on the data.

I *think* I can use `split.data.frame` to turn my original data frame into a list of specific subsets of the original data frame, but I'm having trouble getting the arguments right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each column to be an individual data frame?

```
lapply(2:ncol(df), function (j) df[c(1, j)])
```

The solution with `split` is doing no good here. If you want to split up every single column, the algorithm that `split` does is actually an overhead. Learn more about `split` from [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

If you have difficulty understanding the code, do it in two steps.

```
# define a function
f <- function (j) df[c(1, j)]

## try the function to see that it does
f(2)
f(3)

# use a lapply loop
result <- lapply(2:ncol(df), f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Someone provided this solution in a comment a while back, but it looks like that thread was deleted. This is the solution that I used and it has solved my problem!