# Group dataframe by using a row in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I would like to group my data frame using a certain row. For example, if I have the following data frame;

```
Client  A  A  A  A  A  B  B  B  B  B
Figure 33 45 66 77 88 99 55 66 55 22
```

I would like to split the data frame by `Client` such that the resulting data frame will be as follows;

```
Client  A  A  A  A  A
Figure 33 45 66 77 88

Client  B  B  B  B  B
Figure 99 55 66 55 22
```

I have tried to use `data <- split( df , f = df$Client )` but this requires the data to be vertical than horizontal and the result will be a list and not a data frame. I would want the final groups of data split by Client to be beneath each other as I have indicated and for it to be a data frame such that I will be able to export it to excel as it is

Comment: Are `Client` and `Figure` row or column names?

Comment: Client and Figure are row names

Comment: In `base R` you would need `split.default`.

Comment: Related [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158589/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-r-cores-split-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  split(.$V1) %>%
  map(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base` solution

```
clientVec <- unique(df['client',])
# with lapply
out <- lapply(seq_along(clientVec), function (k) df[,df['client',] == clientVec[k]])
out
# [[1]]
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# client "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# figure "36" "81" "47" "90"
# 
# [[2]]
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# client "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
# figure "95" "14" "58" "91"
```

If you want a data frame instead, then just use `do.call(rbind, ...)`

```
do.call(rbind, out)
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# client "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# figure "36" "81" "47" "90"
# client "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
# figure "95" "14" "58" "91"
```

with the data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- t(data.frame(client = rep(LETTERS[1:2],c(4L,4L)), figure = sample(10:100, 8L, replace = TRUE)))
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# client "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
# figure "36" "81" "47" "90" "95" "14" "58" "91"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution. We can split the column name of your data frame based on the `Client` row, and then use that to select the columns from the original data frame. The final result in is `dat_list`.

Although it may be unrelated, but I want to point out that the format of your data frame is uncommon because all columns are characters. It seems like the `Client` row is the column name of your data frame, but since you mentioned that `Client` and `Figure` are row names, and the column names are usually not duplicated the `Client` row cannot be the column name.

```
dat_list <- lapply(split(names(dat), unlist(dat[1, ])), function(x) dat[, x])

dat_list
# $A
#        V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# Client  A  A  A  A  A
# Figure 33 45 66 77 88
# 
# $B
#        V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# Client  B  B  B  B   B
# Figure 99 55 66 55  22
```

**DATA for dat**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A  A  A  A  A  B  B  B  B  B
33 45 66 77 88 99 55 66 55 22",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

row.names(dat) <- c("Client", "Figure")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Pawel Chabros's answer, but combining resulting elements of the list into a matrix as requested:

```
df %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  split(.$Client) %>%
  map(t) %>% 
  reduce(rbind)
```