# Splitting a data frame into N subsets with equal number of columns

Tags: r

How can I divide my data-frame which have 250 columns into 5 subsets with 50 columns each and assign them into 5 different variables?

I have tried this

```
df2 <- split(df, sample(1:5, ncol(df), replace=T))
```

But this only splits based on number rows but not on number of columns

```
And I want something like this
ncol(df2_1) = 50
ncol(df2_2) = 50
ncol(df2_3) = 50
ncol(df2_4) = 50
ncol(df2_5) = 50
```

And these should include independent columns.

Comment: You need `split.default` for this task, not `split`.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158589/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-r-cores-split-function)

Comment: Hi, @markus thanks for pointing out the useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using comments by @markus, to use split.default, we can modify the initial code, and change the sampling so we get exactly 50 in each subset,

Making some dummy data,

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:250, ncol = 250))
```

Then splitting, (we split this way because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158589/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-r-cores-split-function), pointed out by @markus, this is a more safe/robust version)

```
df2 <- lapply(split.data.frame(t(df), sample(rep(1:5, ncol(df)/5))), t)
```

A less robust, but more simple option is:

```
df2 <- split.default(df, sample(rep(1:5, ncol(df)/5)))
```

gives us,

```
> ncol(df2$`1`)
[1] 50
> ncol(df2$`2`)
[1] 50
> ncol(df2$`3`)
[1] 50
> ncol(df2$`4`)
[1] 50
> ncol(df2$`5`)
[1] 50
```

Comment: Thanks @Hector, for explaining this really well. It worked.